# I don't know why this program only prints "Child Complete"(UNIX)

Tags: c, unix

I'm a beginner of UNIX. these days I am taking a class about operating system. In lecture materials there is a code below.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<unistd.h>
int main()
int main()
{
    pid_t  pid;
    //for a child program
    pid=fork();

    if (pid<0){
            fprintf(stderr,"Fork Failed\n");
            exit(-1);
    }
    else if(pid==0){//child process

            printf("I am the child %d\n",pid);    //not working
            execlp("/bin/ls","ls",NULL);
    }
    else{//parent process
            //parent will wait for the child to complete
            printf("I am the parent %d\n",pid);   //not working
            wait(NULL);
            printf("Child Complete\n");
            exit(0);
    }
}
```

and i expected the result of this program is (file name is fig3-9.c and execute file is a.out)

```
I am the child 0
a.out concurrent.c fig3-9.c, fig3-11.c
I am the parent (som value)
Child Complete
```

but real result is below

```
a.out concurrent.c fig3-9.c, fig3-11.c

Child Complete
```

I don't know why this program doesn't prinf("I am the child %d\n",pid) and ("I am the parent %d\n")

thanks for your helps

Comment: Your lines `int main()` and `int main()` mean the code doesn't compile.  The line `printf("I am the parent %d\n",pid());` tries to invoke the integer variable `pid` as a function; that won't compile.  That means we can't see what you are running, so we cannot help you.  Please fix the code.  Create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/))
 — the same idea by a different name.  This may be an MCVE once you've fixed the obvious typos.

Comment: Incidentally, the header that should be used for [`wait()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/wait.html) is `<sys/wait.h>`, not just `<wait.h>`.  It may accidentally work, but the standard header name is `<sys/wait.h>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can run ok as below code.please use getpid() not pid().
man2 getpid[enter link description here](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getpid.2.html)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<wait.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<unistd.h>
int main()
{
    pid_t  pid;
    //for a child program
    pid=fork();

    if (pid<0){
            fprintf(stderr,"Fork Failed\n");
            exit(-1);
    }
    else if(pid==0){//child process

            printf("I am the child %d\n",getpid());    //not working
            execlp("/bin/ls","ls",NULL);
    }
    else{//parent process
            //parent will wait for the child to complete
            printf("I am the parent %d\n",getpid());   //not working
            wait(NULL);
            printf("Child Complete\n");
            exit(0);
    }
}
```

run result:

```
future@ubuntu:~/work/tmp$ ./a.out 
I am the parent 7383
I am the child 7384
a.out  reverse_slist.c  seg_ment.c  unix_fork_print.c
Child Complete
```

Comment: Oops I have some mistakes sorry about that. I fixed the code but the result is same. I execute the code on UNIX environment my school professor made by themself. maybe this causes the different result of this program?

Comment: Oh! I had another mistake. I didnt make a new executable file. so my result was different... I should study more

Comment: regarding: `#include<wait.h>`   on ubuntu linux, this does not properly compile.  it should be: `#include <sys/wait.h>`